# Key with alias apollo doesn't have a private key

Tags: spring, saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to modify your sample project to read IDP metadata from our company, and followed your procedure exactly: create "signature.cer" file by importing content from IDP metadata by my company, and then generating the jsk file by using 
`keytool -importcert -alias adfssigning -keystore samlKeystore.jks -file signature.cer`.

Finally, put the .jks file under the folder of "**src\main\resources\security**", put "**FederationMetadata.xml**" under folder of "**src\main\resources\metadata**".

However, it gives me below error when I ran your sample project, this "private key" error gave a big headache. Please help.

Here is some of the contents in my securityContext.xml:

```
<!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer">
    <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
```

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                <constructor-arg value="/metadata/FederationMetadata.xml"/>
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
```

```
<bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                <!-- URL containing the metadata -->
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value   type="java.lang.String">https://companyIDPServer/FederationMetadata/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="int">15000</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>
```

```
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Key with alias apollo doesn't have a private key
    at** org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.getServerKeyInfo(MetadataGenerator.java:209) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.buildSPSSODescriptor(MetadataGenerator.java:329) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.generateMetadata(MetadataGenerator.java:189) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.processMetadataInitialization(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:127) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:86) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:348) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:173) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
```

Comment: 1. Why do you import the certificate into the keystore?
2. You may provide the output of 'keytool -list -keystore PATH_TO/samlKeystore.jks', this will tell if alias 'apollo' is still a 'privateKeyEntr'

sample output

apollo, Jan 1, 2013, PrivateKeyEntry,

Comment: Thank you for the response. 1. We need our app talk to our company IDP  2. Here is the result of list: D:\temp>keytool -list -keystore samlKeystore.jks
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

apollo, Jan 24, 2020, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 32:F3:17:49:74:A1:94:54:1B:98:D0:74:B6:33:1D:77:
56:AC:84:82

Comment: `1 entry apollo, Jan 24, 2020, trustedCertEntry`
It's only a 'cert', which encloses the public key.  You need a private key. You have to properly generate the key.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bernhard Thalmayr said you need to generate the private key to use. With `OpenSSL` you can generate it:

```
genrsa -des3 -out as_priv_key.key 2048
req -new -key as_priv_key.key -sha256  -out as_csr.csr
x509 -req -days 365 -in as_csr.csr -signkey as_priv_key.key -sha256 -out as_crt.crt
pkcs12 -export -out as_pfx.pfx -inkey as_priv_key.key -in as_crt.crt
```

Now you need to use java `keytool` to import the keys:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore as_pfx.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore yourjks.jks -deststoretype JKS -destalias apollo -srcalias 1
```

Only after that you can import the IdP certificate as you are already doing.

Explanation: Your APP is actin as SP (Service Provider) and need a Certificate (with PrivateKey) to Encrypt/Sign SAML messages that are going to be sent to IdP (Identity Provider).

Tip: Be aware the passwords you are using in `securityContext.xml`, you must inform one for `JSK` and another to the `PrivateKey`. Use `keytool -h` to learn how to change these passwords case you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I have passed this hurdle. But stuck with the old good friend of "NameID element must be present as part of the Subject in the Response message, please enable it in the IDP configuration", and worse yet, our ADFS server guy won't collaborate with me to configure the server, I tried to populate nameId on the fly the issue still exists. Any hint on that? Anybody?

Comment: Ah, ok!! For `NameID` problem, take a look at here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-idp-guide.html#chapter-idp-guide-adfs-sp